# Cypress testing cy.focused() optional

Tags: cypress

We are using a custom function in Cypress to select a dropdown. There are 2 dropdown types the function deals with single (can only select 1 option of many) and multiselect (can select multiple option of many).

There is a `.blur()` call needed in the case of the multiselect option, since there seems to be some element that gets the focus. This is not the case for the single select and causes the `.blur()` call to fail. `cy.focused()` also fails for the same reason.

What is the best way to conditionally check if some element is focused or not?

Is there something that can be done similar to what is shown below, without failing the test when there is no focused element.

```js
cy.focused().then((element) => { 
  if(element) {
    element.blur();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The cypress definition for blur has a comment that might give you a useful way forward.

> ```js
>    /**
>     * Blur a focused element. This element must currently be in focus.
>     * If you want to ensure an element is focused before blurring,
>     * try using .focus() before .blur().
>     *
>     * @see https://on.cypress.io/blur
>     */
>    blur(options?: Partial<BlurOptions>): Chainable<Subject>
> ```

so maybe if you `focus()` the `<body>` element and then `bur()` you will get the effect you want

```js
cy.get('body')
  .focus()      // whatever previously had focus loses it here
  .blur()       // triggers a blur event
```

---

**Which element is active?**

Under the hood, Cypress `focused()` query uses [document.activeElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement) native DOM selector to find which element (if any) has the focus.

Then, you can use the same

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('blurIfFocused', () => {
  cy.document().then(doc => {
    const activeElement = doc.activeElement
    if (activeElement !== null) {
      cy.wrap(activeElement).blur()
    }
  })
})

...

cy.blurIfFocused()
```